Is is possible in CSS to have different Image height/width according to the browser size: mobile/wide screen
Is is possible in CSS to have different Image height/width according to the browser size.
For example, in the image below, I have set the image to 250px X 250px for wide screen.  I however want it to change to 150px X 150px if a user is on a mobile phone.
<img  class="block  w-full" src="{{asset($image)}}"
 style='width: 250px; height: 250px; object-fit: cover;'/>


The <picture> element allows you to specify different source images based on media conditions, which is often the best approach for speed as it means you aren't serving a large image and just shrinking down the display size for mobile.
<picture>
  <source srcset="large_image.jpg" media="(min-width: 600px)" />
  <img src="small_image.jpg" />
</picture>

If you need to use css, then you need to use media queries.  These won't work inline, however, and need to be in a style sheet.  It'll be something like this.
img.w-full {
  width: 150px;
  width: 150px;
}

@media (min-width: 600px) {
  img.w-full {
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
  }
}


hi @RichardB. thank for your help. Question. if i use the 'srcset' picture element can you still use CSS and height/width styling ?

Yes, you can still use CSS to style images when using the srcset attribute with the  element or the  tag.
it's like this @RichardB?
